# Simple IOS Layout

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, storyboard

I have been trying to do this layout for a few days now and cannot do it. I have no code as I have been only using Storyboard.

In my Android version I simply used a weighted LinearLayout where my title was 20% my relative layout was 60% and my custom object was 20%.

I cannot replicate this in IOS. Everything I try fails. I have tried everything and have tried using StackViews, EqualHeight constraints with multipliers and everything does not work. Most of the time nothing even happens and it just looks the same. Can someone please help me? I am so frustrated I am considering abandoning XCode in total and coding my app in React Native.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't have any code to show, but perhaps you could add a screen shot of your storyboard scene and a sketch of what you are trying to achieve.  As it stands, it isn't clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking. But if you want to use storyboards, it's pretty easy with XCode.  You can set your layout visually, then simply use the "auto-resolve" feature (little triangle inside of bars on bottom right above the console) to: 1) "clear constraints" and then 2) "reset to suggested constraints".  This is a fast and crude method that should more than enough to get started.